# Copy data from one sheet to another based on field value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a file with 10 sheets.
They are named:
 - MAIN_FIELDS
 - ENGLISH
 - GERMAN
 - FRENCH
 - SPANISH
etc...

Inside MAIN_FIELDS I have a field containing the language (col:C row:11)
Under that field I got a lot of fields filled out with data from what ever sheet I choose when I type into the Language

Lets say I type ENGLISH and want the content of F3 in the ENGLISH sheet.
(or as you normally would do it  =ENGLISH!F3)

I tried these:

=C11!F3

=$C$11!F3

='C11'!F3

='''+C11+'''!F3

="" & C11 & ""!F3

None of them work.

Anyone have an idea if this is possible (without doing a looooooong if statement :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
=INDIRECT(C11&"!F3")
```

Comment: If that solved your problem, please accept the answer by clicking on the green tick mark to the left of this answer

Comment: Thats a cool function, I can even do it over multiple sheets   =INDIRECT(Activate!C11&"!F3")

Comment: CallumDA I have to wait 10 minutes :-D

Comment: @Moacir  even thou this works great, it will take me a long time to do for 200 fields:

=INDIRECT(C11&"!F3")
=INDIRECT(C11&"!F4")
=INDIRECT(C11&"!F5")
etc...

Is there a way?   I tried this:

=INDIRECT(Activate!$C$11&ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()))

and this

=INDIRECT(Activate!$C$11&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())))

Comment: Try `=INDIRECT(C$11&"!F"&ROW() -8)`

Comment: @Moacir that worked perfectly!!!  Thanks a bunch :)  

=INDIRECT(Activate!$C$11&"!D"&ROW()-1)